# From the Reformed Perspective, What are "The Secret Things that Belong to the Lord"?

Tags: reformed-theology

Given:

> Romans 11:33 (NIV) Oh, the depth of the riches of the wisdom and knowledge of God! How unsearchable his judgments, and his paths beyond tracing out!
>
> Isaiah 55:9 (NIV) As the heavens are higher than the earth, so are my ways higher than your ways and my thoughts than your thoughts.
>
> Deuteronomy 29:29 (NIV) The secret things belong to the LORD our God, but the things revealed belong to us and to our children forever, that we may follow all the words of this law.

I would like to know the Reformed/Calvinist's general consensuses on which questions are "forbidden" for men to ask. Or rather - questions whose answers are "Man is not meant to know that" or "You just need to accept what the Bible says about that" or "That is a High Mystery".